# Extract Sender IP's from emails in an Outlook (2010) Folder

Tags: email, outlook, ip, sender

To be clear, I want to extract the sender IP's from a **GROUP** of emails without going to file | properties on every single one. There are a great many to go through.

Output to a text file would be fine.

I am wondering if this is possible? Perhaps there's an app for that!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a programming question? You would need to extract the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F`) using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty and parse the data explicitly in your code. The IP address is not guaranteed to be there of course.

Comment: that sounds good I'll give that a shot. Thanks for the fast response.